# Perl Modules Mail::POP3Client and Net::Pop3 Aren't working with pop.gmail.com or pop.aol.com

Tags: perl, gmail, pop3

The issue seems to be with the types of authorization that these modules are able to provide, as shown in the text example hereunder.

How do I get around this?

```
use Net::Netrc;
use Mail::POP3Client;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $server=Net::Netrc->lookup($ARGV[0]) or die ".netrc entry not found\n";
my ($login, $pass) = $server->lpa       or die "Login or password not found\n";
print $login."  ".$pass."\n";  # DB3

my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new( PeerAddr => $ARGV[0],
                                         PeerPort => 995,
                                         Proto    => 'tcp') || die "No socket!";
my $pop = Mail::POP3Client->new();
      $pop->Debug(1);
      $pop->User($login);
      $pop->Pass($pass);
      $pop->Socket($socket);
      $pop->Connect();
--
POP3 <- +OK Gpop ready for requests from ...
POP3 <- SASL PLAIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER
 at ./BpGet.pl line 19.
POP3 <- .
 at ./BpGet.pl line 19.
POP3 -> USER jane
 at ./BpGet.pl line 19.
POP3 <- +OK send PASS
 at ./BpGet.pl line 19.
POP3 -> PASS janepasswd
 at ./BpGet.pl line 19.
POP3 <- -ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted.
```

Comment: Are you sure that authentication with username and password is even enabled for the account? By default at least with gmail it will only accept OAuth (i.e. XOAUTH2) and one has to explicitly allow insecure authentication.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Google now seems to specifically allow "Third-party apps with account access" after a suspicious connection attempt has been validated. So it's telling me that "Ubuntu has full access to your Google Account". But that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You have to explicitly set "Allow less secure apps" to "ON". Then it works for me.

Comment: I can't see any such option.

Comment: This is not a per device/app setting but a general security setting in your account.

Comment: I still can't see an "Allow less secure apps" option. Perhaps it's been removed from recent accounts.

Comment: I've got around the problem by using an AOL account .. which has an option to create automatically a special password for use by a less-secure application.